# How to show Additional Shipping Fee of per product on checkout page by an attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

**I have added an attribute for use on the product page:**

[image]

**Now I would like it show on cart page like this:**

[image]

If the quantity of a product in the cart is increased, I would like the `additional shipping fee` to add and increase the `GrandTotal`

Answer (score 1):

I solve my question by own.In the upper picture you see a attribute is created with the name of addition_shipping_fee.Now you need to do follow step to solve the question.

[image]

Put this code in file:

```
<tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <?php echo 'Additional Shipping Fee'; ?>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getAdditionalShippingFee()) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now Goto:**/app/code/local/Mage/Tax/Block/Checkout/Shipping.php** Put this code:

```
public function getAdditionalShippingFee()
{
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    $additional_fee = 0;
    foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
        $fee = $product->getData('additional_shipping_fee');
        if($fee) {
            $additional_fee += ($item->getQty() * $fee);
        }
    }
    return $additional_fee;
}
```

this code help to get value of **additional_shipping_fee** according to all product Id and product Quantity that already present in quote.

Now we need to add additional fee to order table:

Goto:**/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Grand.php**

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    foreach($address->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
        $fee = $product->getData('additional_shipping_fee');
        if($fee) {
            $additional_fee += ($item->getQty() * $fee);
        }
    }

    $grandTotal     = $address->getGrandTotal();
    $baseGrandTotal = $address->getBaseGrandTotal();

    $store      = $address->getQuote()->getStore();
    $totals     = array_sum($address->getAllTotalAmounts());
    $totals     = $store->roundPrice($totals);
    $baseTotals = array_sum($address->getAllBaseTotalAmounts());
    $baseTotals = $store->roundPrice($baseTotals);

    $address->setGrandTotal($grandTotal+$totals+$additional_fee);
    $address->setBaseGrandTotal($baseGrandTotal+$baseTotals+$additional_fee);
    return $this;
}
```

here **additional_fee** is added in both GrandTotal & BaseGrandTotal.

**Result:**This Will Update value on both increase and decrease condition.

[image]

after this if any query please tell me: